# Windows 11 Intel NUC keeps corrupting EFI partition

Tags: windows, boot, windows-11, uefi

The machine boots into a "a bootable device has not been detected" screen. When booting into the BIOS after this, I don't see the SSD recognized. At this point, I can use the Windows installation media to repair the EFI partition using bcdboot. The installation media recognizes the SSD and I'm able to rebuild the EFI partition. I can boot into Windows just fine after that. But within a couple hours to a day, when I reboot, I'm faced with the no bootable device screen again. It's not every time I reboot either. A few reboots typically work right after I fix it, and then it breaks again. This has happened multiple times.

The first time this happened, I tried updating the BIOS to its latest version to see if that would help but it had no effect. Is the SSD going bad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, Windows 11 does not corrupt the EFI partition on a good machine. Three here, for as long as Windows 11 has been out.

Get the Disk Manufacturer's hardware diagnostic and test the SSD.

I would say a bad SSD (or its controller) is the most likely issue.

Also use Intel's hardware diagnostics to test the entire machine.

SSD or mainboard - there does appear to be a hardware issue.

You can try backing up and reinstalling Windows 11, but from your description, I do not think that is the issue.

Comment: I've tried the manufacturer's diagnostic tool as well as a third party. Both come back with the SSD being in good health. Intel's diagnostic tool also gave a pass on everything. Maybe it is the SSD controller?

Comment: That is probably the issue. Likely intermittent.  Maybe also check the SSD seating.

Comment: After additional testing, it seems the SSD was the problem. I've replaced it and it's been working as expected so far. Thanks for your help.